# About sql query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT E.flmavailable_date,E.flmavailable_num_licenses, flmavailable_product AS SERVER 
FROM (SELECT flmavailable_num_licenses,flmavailable_date 
      FROM licenses_available 
      ORDER BY flmavailable_num_licenses ASC) E 
WHERE flmavailable_product <= 4;
```

Error:---Unknown column 'flmavailable_product' in 'field list'

Even though there is field called by that name I am getting error.
I need help to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

Your outer `select` is trying to select a `flmavailable_product` from your inner `select`, yet there is no such field in that inner query.

Can you include the schema of the licenses_available table and a description of what your query is intended to return?  This would make it easier to help you.  Based on your query as it stands, it seems like you might not need that inner subquery.

Comment: I need to get top license user

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the flmavailable_product field in the inner sub query if it is a column in the licences_available table, or join to the appropriate table which contains this field in the inner query :

```
 SELECT E.flmavailable_date,E.flmavailable_num_licenses,flmavailable_product AS SERVER  
 FROM (SELECT flmavailable_num_licenses,flmavailable_date, flmavailable_product 
         FROM licenses_available ORDER BY flmavailable_num_licenses ASC)E 
  WHERE flmavailable_product <= 4;
```

Also, not sure why you are using the inner subquery as all it does is a straight select

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you wanted to write.

```
SELECT flmavailable_num_licenses,flmavailable_date, flmavailable_product AS SERVER 
  FROM licenses_available 
  WHERE flmavailable_product <= 4
  ORDER BY flmavailable_num_licenses ASC
```

Comment: There is no need for subquery in this context.

Answer (score 0):

General select query structure is:

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM `table`
WHERE x<=y
```

Here your inner query is acting as a table. However your inner query is returning only two columns: flmavailable_num_licenses & flmavailable_date.

In your outer query, you are getting an error as you are trying to select column 'flmavailable_product' which is not available in the table (Inner query).

This is clearly indicated by the error (Unknown column 'flmavailable_product' in 'field list') you are getting.

To solve this, you need to either select flmavailable_product in inner query or if it is not present there, use join to join the tables where required column is present.

Please provide table structure for exact query.